# SSRS Validate different results from same column

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

I hope my phrasing is right in asking this question - this query is pulling invoices and the items on the invoices are accessible by line - I'm trying to validate whether the xx_isfunctionalservice is yes and no on the same table - this should always be true

```
SELECT     ONP_C_ORDERLINE.C_ORDER_ID, ONP_C_ORDERLINE_1.C_ORDER_ID
FROM         ONP_C_ORDERLINE INNER JOIN
                  ONP_M_PRODUCT ON ONP_C_ORDERLINE.M_PRODUCT_ID = ONP_M_PRODUCT.M_PRODUCT_ID INNER JOIN
                  ONP_C_ORDERLINE AS ONP_C_ORDERLINE_1 ON ONP_C_ORDERLINE.C_ORDERLINE_ID = ONP_C_ORDERLINE_1.C_ORDERLINE_ID AND 
                  ONP_M_PRODUCT.M_PRODUCT_ID = ONP_C_ORDERLINE_1.M_PRODUCT_ID INNER JOIN
                  ONP_M_PRODUCT AS ONP_M_PRODUCT_1 ON ONP_C_ORDERLINE.M_PRODUCT_ID = ONP_M_PRODUCT_1.M_PRODUCT_ID
WHERE     (ONP_M_PRODUCT.XX_ISFUNCTIONALSERVICE = 'y') AND (ONP_M_PRODUCT_1.XX_ISFUNCTIONALSERVICE = 'n')
GROUP BY ONP_C_ORDERLINE.C_ORDER_ID, ONP_C_ORDERLINE_1.C_ORDER_ID
```

I tried doing this from the same table, which makes no sense - I was hoping bringing up another table would let me compare two different values from the same table. I could do this with two queries, I'm sure, easier, but I would prefer to keep this clean

Comment: Not 100% clear on your requirement - do you need `xx_isfunctionalservice IN ('y','n')` ?

Comment: you can tell I'm an SQL novice - that seems to be doing the trick

Comment: that being said, this was a query to test true data - what I'm trying to do is actually exclude anything that shows 'y' and 'n' grouped by the same doc_id

Comment: I guess NOT IN('y','n') would seem a logical opposite... now I have to figure out a good way to test.. since it's returning nothing, even though that's what I want

Comment: I suppose to test you try `NOT IN ('y')` and ensure your 'n' entries show, then swap to `n` and try the same. I'll put my comment in the answer so the question isn't left "unanswered". Cheers.

Comment: looks great, thanks for entertaining my problem - I tend to make things too complicated :)

Comment: No problem, can you tick this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get checks for 'y' or 'n' the neatest solution is to use `IN`

ie:

```
xx_isfunctionalservice IN ('y','n')
```